# C# creating LinkedPixels from a Bitmap in an Optimized way

Tags: c#, multithreading, optimization, bitmap, hashset

I am doing image manipulation, I have a class that I've inherited that I can't change because it's referenced too many times to completely refactor. Here is the class as it stands.

I have a Bitmap and I am trying to get a collection of all of the LinkedPixels. For example pixel

x, y would be a key and a pixel in the center would be attached to four pixels, (x+1, y), (x, y + 1), (x-1, y), (y-1, x). Pixels on the sides would have three attached Pixels, and Pixels in the corners only two.

**imWrap.Arr is an array with all of the Pixels inside of a Bitmap, this is built as the program spools up so this is not built on the fly it is already available.**

**Since I cannot change the class itself (I could change it to a struct if necessary) I need to find the fastest way to create the LinkedPix, I am aware that there are many better ways to do this but I am locked in to this "LinkedPix" class, there are over 100 references to it**

```
   public class LinkedPix
   {
       public Point P;

       public override string ToString()
       {
           return P.ToString() + " " + Links.Count;
       }

       public HashSet<LinkedPix> Links;
       public SegObject MemberOfObject { get; set; }
       public bool IsMemberOfObject { get => MemberOfObject != null; }

       private void Init()
       {
           MemberOfObject = null;
           Links = new HashSet<LinkedPix>();
       }

       public LinkedPix(int x, int y)
       {
           Init();
           P = new Point(x, y);
       }

       public LinkedPix(Point p)
       {
           Init();
           P = p;
       }

       public LinkedPix RotateCopy(double theta_radians)
       {
           //Assumes that 0,0 is the origin
           LinkedPix LP2 = new LinkedPix(new Point(
               (int)(P.X * Math.Cos(theta_radians) - P.Y * Math.Sin(theta_radians)),
               (int)(P.Y * Math.Cos(theta_radians) + P.X * Math.Sin(theta_radians))));
           return LP2;
       }

       public void LinksRemove(LinkedPix ToRemove, bool TwoWay = false)
       {
           //Remove from each others
           if (TwoWay) ToRemove.Links.Remove(this);
           Links.Remove(ToRemove);
       }

       /// <summary>
       /// Removes this from each of its links and removes these links
       /// </summary>
       internal void LinksCrossRemove()
       {
           foreach (LinkedPix tPix in Links) tPix.LinksRemove(this, false);
           Links = new HashSet<LinkedPix>();
       }
   }
```

Here are the three functions I used to populate the information about how LinkedPix are related.

```
   Dictionary<Point, LinkedPix> PointDict = new Dictionary<Point, LinkedPix>();
   void EstablishLinks(int xi, int yi, LinkedPix Pixi)
          {
              if (imWrap.Arr[xi, yi] > threshold)
              {
                  Point pi = new Point(xi, yi);
                  LinkedPix Pix2 = GetOrAdd(pi);
                  Pixi.Links.Add(Pix2);
                  Pix2.Links.Add(Pixi);
              }
          }

          LinkedPix Pix; Point p;
          int height = imWrap.Height;
          for (int y = 0; y < height - 1; y++)
          {
              if (Slice && y % Slice_ModulusFactor < 1) continue; //This is for Axon Degeneration to break up the axons
              for (int x = 0; x < height - 1; x++)
              {
                  if (Slice && x % Slice_ModulusFactor < 1) continue;
                  if (imWrap.Arr[x, y] > threshold)
                  {
                      Pixels++;
                      if (CreateLinks)
                      {
                          p = new Point(x, y);
                          Pix = GetOrAdd(p);
                          if (y + 1 < height) EstablishLinks(x, y + 1, Pix);
                          if (x + 1 < height) EstablishLinks(x + 1, y, Pix);
                      }
                  }
              }
          }
      }


      public LinkedPix GetOrAdd(Point p)
      {
          if (PointDict.ContainsKey(p))
          {
              return PointDict[p];
          }
          else
          {
              LinkedPix LP = new LinkedPix(p);
              PointDict.Add(p, LP);
              return LP;
          }
      }
  }
```

imWrap.Arr[x, y] is an array that has already been pre-populated with the contents of a bitmap.

things I have tried

1. Switching to ConcurrentDictionaries and running in Parallel. The inferior Hashing Algorithm of ConcurrentDictionary compared to HashSet means running this in Parallel actually takes more time, at least when I tried it.
2. switching to a different collection with faster adds such as a Que. This gains me some speed but because of the way LinkedPix is used, **I ultimately have to convert to a HashSet anyway** which costs time in the end so this is not ultimately a win.
3. Various types of Asynchronicity, I either gain very little or nothing at all.

I'm definitely stuck and could use some outside of the box thinking. I definitely need to speed this up and any help would be greatly appreciated.

These are some timings

```
     GetOrAdd: 4.190254371881144 ticks
        LinksAdd: 1.7282694093881512 ticks
        LinksAddTwo: 1.6570632131524925 ticks
        PointCreateTime: 0.20380008184398646 ticks
        ArrayCheck: 0.3061780882729328 ticks
```

Comment: First things first, representing a pixel by a class is a terrible idea for performance.

Comment: when I rename LinkedPix Struct performance is even worse because of the number of Structs that end up getting created (I could try and use references to the struct everywhere but that is not always practical.